# Opening plot window from PyQGIS processing script

Tags: pyqgis, matplotlib

I have this script which creates an elevation profile with annotated points in a matplotlib.pyplot window.

It works perfectly in the console, but I want to add it to the QGIS toolbox so it can be run without opening the python console and editor (and so additional files/layers can be selected before running).

The algorithm is just the code wrapped in QGIS's QgsProcessingAlgorithm class.
Running it crashes QGIS and I'm pretty sure it hangs at .show().

**PyQt5 example plot that works**

```
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        sc.axes.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [10,1,20,3,40])

        # Create toolbar, passing canvas as first parament, parent (self, the MainWindow) as second.
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar(sc, self)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(sc)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.show()
        print('[end of main window]')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
print('[FINISHED]')
```

**processing script that doesn't**

```
from qgis.core import (
    QgsProcessing,
    QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
    QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback,
    QgsProcessingParameterFile,
    QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer,
    QgsProject,
    QgsPoint)
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from PyQt5 import (QtCore, 
    QtGui, 
    QtWidgets)
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg, 
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import os
import sys
import processing

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=18, height=5, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()#*args, **kwargs)

        sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        sc.axes.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [10,1,20,3,40])

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar(sc, self)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(sc)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.show()
        print('[FINISHED]')

class PlotProfileAKO(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFile('DrillingProgram', 'Drilling Program', behavior=QgsProcessingParameterFile.File, fileFilter='All Files (*.*)', defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}
        
        w = MainWindow()
        QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        
        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        return {}

    def name(self):
        return 'Plot Profile AKO test 1'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Plot Profile AKO test 1'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return PlotProfileAKO()
```

Comment: What you need is a PyQT5 canvas to show your plot on. You could try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29791498/5874767

Comment: Thankyou @DrorBogin I have tried to start a QtWidget however QGIS crashes at the same point (self.show()). Is QgsProcessingAlgorithm the right class to use, or could QgsPythonRunner work?